# Add this little jquery action in wordpress using button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, button

I have this really little piece of code which I want to implement inside word press:

```
<div id='cont' style="border: 1px solid #000; height: 150px; overflow:hidden;">
    <a href="#" id="button">Mostrar Todo</a>
    <ul>
        <li>an item</li>
        <li>an item</li>
        <li>an item</li>
        <li>an item</li>
        <li>an item</li>
        <li>an item</li> 
        <li>an item</li>
        <li>an item</li>
        <li>an item</li>
        <li>an item</li>
        <li>an item</li>
         <li>an item</li>
        <li>an item</li>
        <li>an item</li>
        <li>an item</li>
        <li>an item</li>

    </ul>
</div>`
```

jquery function I want to do

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    $('#cont').animate({height:'500px'}, 500);

});
```

demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/YPAy6/9/

I simply need how or where to put the "function" and how to call it from a post in wordpress.

Any idea? really thanks!

PD: I'm loading all scripts from google's cdn and as far as I know its not necessary to load any other jquery cos wordpress its loading also its own version, anyway I'm not 110% sure about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to execute the said jQuery function on your WP site, you will have to load it through a `.js` file first. Copy and save it as, say, `functions.js` and place it in a folder called /js/ your theme directory (/wp-content/themes/[theme-name]).

In order to load scripts on your site, you can use the good old way of `<script src="..." />` in the `<head>` element, but I strongly recommend using `wp_enqueue_script` instead. (see [WP codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) for more information).

Add the `wp_enqueue_scripts()` function to your theme's `functions.php`:

```
<?php
function site_functions_js() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'site_functions',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/functions.js',
        array('jquery')
    );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'site_functions_js');
?>
```

Comment: ok, all done, but it does nothing, maybe something related with no conflict mode? (I've used wp_enqueue) sorry if some questions are so basic, but this is so basic and I'm getting messed -__-

Comment: You should check upon page load using the developer tools in the browser, and see if the JS file is successfully loaded.

Comment: wel wel wel, now I'm testing in a sandbox site, the script is loading and developer tools says something is wrong with the js file, (most sure I did something wrong) (http://noslan.com/customers/sandbox/?p=60)  suggestions? :)

Comment: On a side note, if you're unsure if a JS file is loaded properly or working, just use the good old `alert()` function to check ;)

Answer (score 0):

Make a new javascript file and put this function in that file, and put this Javascript file AFTER the wp_head function.
Like this :-

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/js/yourScript.js">   </script>
```

For more Details use this link :-

http://digwp.com/2009/06/including-jquery-in-wordpress-the-right-way/

Comment: is it really necessary? I mean, this is a jquery function and jquery is loaded by WP or I have a huge mess in my mind?

Comment: ok, as I can see the best practice when various scripts are loaded is enqueue scripts. Your answer seems also legitim but not actual, or m I wrong?